# Envió de correo cada vez que haya un insert

Tags: c#

Tengo una **dataGridView** que se llena por medio de un procedimiento almacenado, y un **timer** que recarga la tabla cada 5 segundos para que me muestre en tiempo real las filas agregadas, es decir cada vez que inserten algo en la tabla en sql server me muestre en el dataGridView, lo que necesito es enviar un correo cada vez que se agregue un dato, es decir cada vez que haya un insert, como puedo hacer el envió y como puedo optimizar el Refresh de la tabla para quitar el timer

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AlertaPDC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand();
        private SqlDataReader LeerFilas;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListarTraslados();
            SetTimer();
        }

        private SqlConnection Connection()
        {
            return new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.; Password=S0p0rt3;user=sa;DataBase=PRU");
        }

        public DataTable ListarPDC()
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = Connection();
            DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
            conexion.Open();
            Comando.Connection = conexion;
            Comando.CommandText = "SP_ALERTAPDC";
            Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            LeerFilas = Comando.ExecuteReader();
            Tabla.Load(LeerFilas);
            LeerFilas.Close();
            conexion.Close();
            return Tabla;
        }

        public void ListarTraslados()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ListarPDC();
        }


        private void SetTimer()
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }


        private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)ListarTraslados);
        }


        private void Envio() 
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("esteban4g@gmail.com", "krestrepo@poricarnes.com", "RESOLUCION DE FACTURACION CREDITO PROXIMA A VENCER", "La resolucion de facturacion  de el punto de venta X, Consecutivos restantes: " + resolucionFa);
            //Si tu servidor smtp necesita credenciales, las pones asi
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("soportesistemas@gmail.com.co", "Sopor19*");
            //Finalmente envias el mensaje
            client.Send(message);

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: en tu código hay varias cuentas de correo electronico. Si son reales, deberías censurarlas o eliminarlas

Comment: Los correos y contraseñas están alteradas, gracias

Comment: Tal vez haciendo uso de [Service Broker](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15) podrías configurar un servicio de mensajes entre sql server y tu aplicación...pero yo no tengo experiencia con ello, no puedo decirte mucho mas

Comment: ¿Dónde está el código del `insert` ?

Comment: El insert lo hacen desde una app externa que llena una tabla de sql server yo capturo ese insert y envió una notificación

Comment: Y la solucion que has aceptado es lo que buscabas? En ese caso, creo que no entendí tu pregunta la verdad :)

Comment: Cada vez que se recargue la tabla y haya un registro nuevo envié un correo electrónico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente necesitas controlar 2 cosas: Cuando abres el formulario y cuando vas rellenando el datagridView. Y para ello, he creado 2 variables a nivel de formulario llamados `cargaInicial` (por defecte, false) y `registrosActuales`, que se encargará de guardar los registros que tenemos actualmente en el datagridView.

Por lo tanto:

- `cargaInicial` se encargará de controlar que no envie un correo cuando estamos abriendo el formulario, ya que estamos rellenando el datagridView por primera vez.
- `registrosActuales` controla el nº de registros actuales del datagridView. Si cambia y es inferior a los registros que vienen por BBDD, enviaremos un correo y asignamos el nuevo valor. De este modo, la próxima vez que se dispare el timer, si no hay novedades, no enviará ningún correo.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AlertaPDC
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand();
        private SqlDataReader LeerFilas;

        private bool cargaInicial = false;
        private int registrosActuales = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListarTraslados();
            cargaInicial = true;
            SetTimer();
        }

        private SqlConnection Connection()
        {
            return new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.; Password=S0p0rt3;user=sa;DataBase=PRU");
        }

        public DataTable ListarPDC()
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = Connection();
            DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
            conexion.Open();
            Comando.Connection = conexion;
            Comando.CommandText = "SP_ALERTAPDC";
            Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            LeerFilas = Comando.ExecuteReader();

            // Si no es la carga inicial y el nº de registros actuales es inferior a los devueltos, quiere decir que se ha añadido un registro
            // Por lo tanto, envío un email y guardo el nuevo valor en la variable registrosActuales
            if (!cargaInicial && registrosTotales < LeerFilas.count){
                Envio();
                registrosTotales = LeerFilas.count;
            }

            Tabla.Load(LeerFilas);
            LeerFilas.Close();
            conexion.Close();
            return Tabla;
        }

        public void ListarTraslados()
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ListarPDC();
        }


        private void SetTimer()
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }


        private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)ListarTraslados);
        }


        private void Envio() 
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("esteban4g@gmail.com", "krestrepo@poricarnes.com", "RESOLUCION DE FACTURACION CREDITO PROXIMA A VENCER", "La resolucion de facturacion  de el punto de venta X, Consecutivos restantes: " + resolucionFa);
            //Si tu servidor smtp necesita credenciales, las pones asi
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("soportesistemas@gmail.com.co", "Sopor19*");
            //Finalmente envias el mensaje
            client.Send(message);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que parcero mas teso, la buena pa